# Change react-native ScrollView color

Tags: react-native

I have a problem with ScrollView in React-Natives. I've already looked for it in the react-native docs, but still unable to find it. Because of this I need to include an image since I don't even know how to call it.

[image]

**Is it possible to change the "purple" color in this picture? How? And what is this "purple" thing called?**

Here's my code to give a clue.

The ScrollView:

```
    <ScrollView
      horizontal={true}
      showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
      style={style.scrollContainer}
      endFillColor="#000"
    >
```

The styles

```
  scrollContainer: {
    marginTop: 20,
    marginHorizontal: 10,
    color: "#fff",
  },
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the `overScroll glow effect` on android devices and can be disabled using the [overScrollMode prop](https://reactnative.dev/docs/scrollview#overscrollmode-android). You need to set it to `never` as follows.

```js
<ScrollView
      horizontal={true}
      showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
      style={style.scrollContainer}
      endFillColor="#000"
      overScrollMode="never"
    >
```

I have created a little [snack](https://snack.expo.dev/@pgrepds/scrollview) that showcases this prop. Notice that I have disabled this for the horizontal scrollview and enabled it for the vertical scrollview.

Changing the color is only possible by adding `<item name="android:colorEdgeEffect">#E53644</item>` to your `styles.xml` as discussed [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/28973), whereby `#E53644` is the hexcode of the color of choice.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, now I know how to disable it, but is it possible to change the color of this ```overScroll glow effect``` ?? I want to change it from purple to grey as example.

Comment: You can only change this globally by adding `<item name="android:colorEdgeEffect">#E53644</item>` in your `styles.xml` as discussed [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/28973).

Comment: it is not working anymore. i have tried.